# How to inherit own class in output class of Google API in python?

Tags: python, inheritance, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints

I created my own Common class for Error messages

```
# for returning error messages
class ErrorMessage(messages.Message):
    errorCode = messages.StringField(1)
    developerMessage = messages.StringField(2)
    userMessage = messages.StringField(3)
```

and Output class of endpoint

```
# output class for GetFriendlyFieldNames
class GetFriendlyFieldNamesOutput(messages.Message):
    friendlyNames = messages.MessageField(GetFriendlyFieldNamesStore,      1,repeated=True)
```

I tried to inherit more than one class to my output class  and changed the above class as

```
# output class for GetFriendlyFieldNames
class GetFriendlyFieldNamesOutput(messages.Message,ErrorMessage):
    friendlyNames = messages.MessageField(GetFriendlyFieldNamesStore, 1,repeated=True)
```

But now this is showing error in logs

"Message types may only inherit from Message"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a restriction of the Google Proto RPC library. In [its source code](https://googleappengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/python/lib/protorpc-1.0/protorpc/messages.py), you'll see that's not possible.

It will allow only one direct sub-class of messages.Message:

```
if bases != (object,):
  # Can only define one level of sub-classes below Message.
  if bases != (Message,):
    raise MessageDefinitionError(
        'Message types may only inherit from Message')
```